# How to Build this complex IF formula

Tags: excel, ms-office, spreadsheet

Note- This Image is for representation. Column 'D', 'E' has around 100 rows

[image]

Here i want to put a Formula in 'G' column field where 7100 appears.

At the moment i am myself calculating 1100 + 1000 + 5000 and adding and writing 7100 in the G column. I want a Formula where Numbers in column 'E' are only added if column 'D' has something written in front of it for e.g: - 10 or 11, or 12, 555 , 666 & so on...... If nothing is written in column 'D' like for e.g:- next to 4000 then this 4000 should not be added to 7100 and likewise the last 'E' field 1000 also will not be added as nothing in written in column 'D' against it.

Requesting for help in coming up with such a formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stick this in any cell in column G

```
=SUMIF(D:D,">0",E:E)
```

Note: this will only work if column D:D has numerical values

Comment: To count if D:D contains _anything_ (alpha or numeric) use `=SUMIF(D:D,"<>",E:E)`

Comment: @chrisneilsen I am terrible with formulas but thanks for the pointer, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`=SUM(E:E) - SUMIF(D:D, "",E:E )`

should do the trick !

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array formula to do a similar thing to @mehow is suggesting, except that is will work with anything in the cell.

Use the following formula (remember to enter it by holding CTRL+SHIFT when you press RETURN or it wont work)

```
=SUM(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(D:D)),E:E,0))
```

If it is entered correctly as an array formula you will see {} around the formula