# Count number of times a value is present only if another value matches

Tags: excel, count, formula

I have two columns in Excel, something like this:

[image]

I want to count the number of times a value is present in column B, ONLY when column A's value is "Stop".  So for this example, the formula would return 2.

I tried

`=COUNTIFS('[sheet]'!B3:B450,"Stop",'[sheet]'!K3:K450,"*")`

but this returns 0.

Comment: "*" only works for text values - in this case you have dates (which are numbers in excel) so mehow's version will fix that

Comment: @barryhoudini I learnt the [`<>` trick from you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951678/how-to-build-this-complex-if-formula/19951834#19951834)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,"=Stop",B:B,"<>")`

Note the use of `"<>"` means the cell is not empty